# How to move through Views without reload them again if I return back Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

I'll give an example of what I want so it's not so confusing:

Example:

Let's say that I have a map that adds every time that my user scrolls 3 annotations dynamically. Now I have a button under the map and when I press it I go to another viewController do what I want and get back to the viewController with the map, now I want to find all the annotations that my map had and not reload the view at all.

I used to use this function that I made to move between viewControllers:

```
func move(identifier: String , viewController : UIViewController) -> Void {
    let mstoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc: UIViewController = mstoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier) 
    viewController.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I also tried this:

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view") as? MyViewcontroller
         self.presentViewController(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

These two when I use them the `viewcontroller` that appears is calling `viewDidload` so its like it appeared for the first time.

Another example is the `tabBarViewController` if you notice when you navigate through tabs nothing reloads (only function that is called is `viewDidAppear` )

EDIT

[test file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sjrz2aieuknd3qq/testing.zip?dl=0)

Comment: If you are using `presentViewController` then you can do a `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` on that controller to get back to the previous one without reloading it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the same project you posted, you instantiate a new `UIViewController` when going from *view 2* back to *view 1* and that is why your `viewDidLoad` gets called again and your entire map view is reloaded.

In your sample project, instead of

```
lazy var mapController2 = { () -> UIViewController in
    let mstoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    return mstoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "first")
}
```

You should just dismiss your *view 2* on the button press.

```
@IBAction func butto(_ sender: AnyObject) {
      //Your initial code
      //PresentingController().moveToMap(self, flag: 1)

      self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

When you present a new `UIViewController`, the older `UIViewController` is not removed from memory, it is just hidden behind the new `UIViewController`. So whenever you wish to go **back** to a `UIViewController` with the previous state maintained, all you need to do is close the new `UIViewController`

**However**, if you are doing some tasks that you performed on your second `UIViewController` that you wish to be reflected in your initial `UIViewController`, you will have to setup closures to update your initial `UIViewController`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will try it and get back to tell you the result as soon as I'll check it

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the fact that the map controller gets deallocated when navigating back to the other controller, and another one is created when you want to move again to the map screen.

What you need is to hold on onto the same controller instance, and present that one. Keeping a strong reference in the presenting controller would suffice.

```
class PresentingController {
    // making the property lazy will result in the getter code
    // being executed only when asked the first time
    lazy var mapController = { () -> UIViewController in
        let mstoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        return mstoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mapControllerIdentifier")
    }()

    func moveToMap() {
        // simply use the mapController property
        // the property reference will make sure the controller won't
        // get deallocated, so every time you navigate to that screen
        // you'll get the same controller
        presentViewController(mapController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry that I didn't reply sooner, I took your code but I have two errors, first  Unable to infer closure return type in current context on the lazy var and Use of unresolved identifier 'present' on present. I use swift 2 by the way

Comment: Thank you I can't test right now but when I do I will inform you

Comment: Again it doesn't work, if you want check the test file I created to show you what I did, I edited my question

Comment: I added a test project I made with your code if you want check it out to see if i missing something, thanks for your help

Comment: A ok now I show the second () I will test it and tell you